# Javaagent. Profiling. klass: 'java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError' when invoke static method from bytecode

Tags: java, profiling, profiler, agent, java-bytecode-asm

I try invoke static method who located in javaagent from application. I inserted method invoke into bytecode:

```
super.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, "JProfOps", "aloc", "()V", false);
```

And when javaagent start I get a

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError 
 - klass: 'java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError'**

**A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
  Internal Error (exceptions.cpp:427), pid=3155, tid=0x00007fe630853700
  fatal error: ExceptionMark destructor expects no pending exceptions**

Manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0  
PreMain-Class: Agent 
Can-Redefine-Classes: true 
Can-Retransform-Classes: true  
Class-Path: asm-all-5.1.jar
```

Run program with **-javaagent:jprof-0.1.jar**

**Boot-Class-Path: jprof-0.1.jar** doesn't help.

jprof-1.0.jar is in classpath.

Comment: Apparently, you are trying to instrument the class `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` itself (or one of its super classes) and provoking a `NoClassDefFoundError`. Did you check whether it works to instrument a more “harmless” class, e.g. on the application class path, in your intended way?

Comment: I get a error when instrumentation `java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleImpl`
But if I instrumentation only my classes or invoke `System.gc` for example, everything works well.

Comment: I don’t think that instrumenting `java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleImpl` is a good idea as there are dependencies to JVM internals. If however, instrumenting a rather harmless class like `java.util.ArrayList` fails as well, it would be a clear sign that the target class (i.e. `JProfOps`) hasn’t been added to the bootstrap class path.

Comment: I resolved this problem. It was necessary to add asm.jar and jprof.jar to boot classpath. Simply add to manifest: `Boot-Class-Path: jprof-0.1.jar asm-all-5.1.jar` But now I get a StackOverflowException  if instrumentation classes from jprof.jar, but now it not critical.